# For loop with sub-process not working

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

```
with open('Client.txt','r') as Client_Name: 
   for Client in Client_Name.readlines(): 
       f=file('data_output','w') 
       p1 = subprocess.Popen(['nbcommand', '-byclient', Client], stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
       p1.wait() 
       f.close()
```

When I use the subprocess with for loop. The output is empty. But if I just #put a client name and run the script the output is fine. How do I loop it for different clients . Any Suggestion ??? Thanks,

```
Client = 'abcd'  
f=file('data_output','w')  
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['nbcommand', '-byclient', Client], stdout=f,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.wait()  
f.close()
```

Comment: Consider using a context manager for the second file as well. Such as with open('data_output','r') as f:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `for Client in Client_Name.readlines()` you get the line with `'\n'` at the end. So you either `rstrip()` that or use `Client_Name.read().splitlines()` to get rid of that new line character, for example:

```
with open('Client.txt','r') as Client_Name: 
    for Client in Client_Name.read().splitlines(): 
        # rest of code
```

or:

```
with open('Client.txt','r') as Client_Name: 
    for Client in Client_Name.readlines(): 
        Client = Client.rstrip()
        # rest of code
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)